# Scrolling Image like http://www.neckermann.de/

Tags: javascript, scriptaculous

I want to write a Javascript like  http://www.neckermann.de/
that scrolls DIV. Where I can get help?

Comment: What's the problem with getting it from the site itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my favourite image rotator: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

It's written very well and likely has more functionality that you'l need!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with jQuery, for example with [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/), the particular effect could be achieved with [something like in this example](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [wipe effect plugin](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/jameslab/wipe/) for scriptaculous a few years back.

You can download it [here](http://scripteka.com/script/wipes).